# Need to remove all leading zeroes from a CSV column that is being converted to text with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, leading-zero

The code is below is adding two columns with rows however when the .CSV file is converted to txt there is an employee id column that lists them as:

```
00001  
00002  
00003  
etc.. Until we get to 10000.
```

I need to remove the leading zeroes in the txt file so they read as...

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
etc.
```

#### Code

```
Import-Csv ECMEmployeeExtract.csv |
  Select-Object *,@{Name='Internal';Expression={'True'}} |
  Select-Object *,@{Name='Location Type';Expression={'Person'}} |
  Export-csv ECMEmployeeExtractUpdate.txt  -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode -Delimiter '
```

#### CSV

```
EMPLID  NAME    LAST NAME   FIRST NAME  MIDDLE NAME NAME SUFFIX REHIRE DT   TERMINATION DT
00001   Phillips, Henry Phillips    Henry           07/23/1962  07/21/1977
00002   Smith, Oscar    Smith   Oscar           03/01/1955  03/10/1988
00006   Kuhfahl, Herman Kuhfahl Herman          11/16/1969  11/17/1990
```

Comment: Please paste the first few lines of your CSV into your question.

Comment: The first few lines of the .csv have been added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following *calculated property* to get the results you expect:

```
@{n='EMPLID';e={[int]$_.EMPLID}}
```

**OR**

```
@{n='EMPLID';e={$_.EMPLID.TrimStart('0')}}
```

- **Example:**

```
@'
EMPLID  NAME    LAST NAME   FIRST NAME  MIDDLE NAME  NAME SUFFIX  REHIRE DT   TERMINATION DT
00001   Phillips, Henry  Phillips    Henry           07/23/1962  07/21/1977
00002   Smith, Oscar     Smith    Oscar           03/01/1955  03/10/1988
00006   Kuhfahl, Herman  Kuhfahl  Herman          11/16/1969  11/17/1990
   Kuhfahl, Herman  Kuhfahl  Herman          11/16/1969  11/17/1990
'@ -replace '  +',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv |
Select-Object @{n='EMPLID';e={[int]$_.EMPLID}},* -ExcludeProperty EMPLID
```

- **Results in:**

```
EMPLID NAME     LAST NAME FIRST NAME MIDDLE NAME NAME SUFFIX REHIRE DT  TERMINATION DT
------ ----     --------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------  --------------
     1 Phillips Henry     Phillips   Henry       07/23/1962  07/21/1977               
     2 Smith    Oscar     Smith      Oscar       03/01/1955  03/10/1988               
     6 Kuhfahl  Herman    Kuhfahl    Herman      11/16/1969  11/17/1990               
     0 Kuhfahl  Herman    Kuhfahl    Herman      11/16/1969  11/17/1990
```

*Bear in mind, if `EMPLID` has no value, this will set the default as `0` (see last row in the example above) if you're using `[int]$_.EMPLID` and an empty value if you're using `$_.EMPLID.TrimStart('0')`.*

---

The actual code should look like this:

```
Import-Csv ECMEmployeeExtract.csv |
Select-Object @{n='EMPLID';e={[int]$_.EMPLID}},*,
              @{Name='Internal';Expression={'True'}},
              @{Name='Location Type';Expression={'Person'}} -ExcludeProperty EMPLID |
Export-Csv ECMEmployeeExtractUpdate.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Which should give you this result:

```
EMPLID NAME     LAST NAME FIRST NAME MIDDLE NAME NAME SUFFIX REHIRE DT  TERMINATION DT Internal Location Type
------ ----     --------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------  -------------- -------- -------------
     1 Phillips Henry     Phillips   Henry       07/23/1962  07/21/1977                True     Person       
     2 Smith    Oscar     Smith      Oscar       03/01/1955  03/10/1988                True     Person       
     6 Kuhfahl  Herman    Kuhfahl    Herman      11/16/1969  11/17/1990                True     Person       
     0 Kuhfahl  Herman    Kuhfahl    Herman      11/16/1969  11/17/1990                True     Person
```

Comment: This solution work well for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @CedricFreamon happy to help. If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as it may be helpful for other in the future.